# When I open php in gnome-terminal -e, I get just empty terminal window

Tags: command-line, php, gnome-terminal, cron

I'm to execute `gnome-terminal -e php /var/scripts/script.php` but I get nothing but empty terminal window without user name, when I do `php /var/scripts/script.php` the terminal is running without problems, how do I show out script's output out in new launched terminal? I want cron some stuff up end end up terminals being here for waiting me to check them out how it's going, because it's gonna happen when I'm not at workstation, and I've got it checked out... It's like 140 outputs I would need to rewrite, if I want to log that, because I haven't used wrapper... I just need terminal to see the stuff anyway.

Comment: Path separator in Linux is `/`, not ``\``.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I had written it correctly in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
gnome-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c 'php \var\scripts\script.php; exec /bin/bash -i'"
```

It is possible that you will need to replace "php" with full path to program, but it should work without that.
You can also use "--tab" argument to open new instances in tabs instead of windows:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "/bin/bash -c 'php \var\scripts\script.php; exec /bin/bash -i'"
```

**Edit:** this assumes that usage of backslash is not an typo, otherwise it would be like this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "/bin/bash -c 'php /var/scripts/script.php; exec /bin/bash -i'"
```